# How to make the vertical scrollbar of a gridview scroll to the bottom on first display after sorting a column in accending order

Tags: vb.net

Am working   on a chat application and am using a gridview to display the chat  messages  I want the scrollbar to be scrolled  automatically  to the bottom so as to show new messages.  I just want the gridview to show the  last row after sorting have taken place

Comment: U need to show more code

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Control.Focus()` or `Control.Select()` on of the items in the last row of your `GridView`. If this doesn't solve your issue, please show more of your code.